# Invalid 'size' argument using RC.pc function of iCAMP

Tags: r, size, normalization

I'm using the `RC.pc` function form `iCAMP` package witch works well on my raw ASV data. But when i rarefy and normalized my data with log and hellinger, I have the error:

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
> 4 nodes produced errors; first error: invalid 'size' argument

I've tried with the `phyloseq` data set `GlobalPatterns` and i'm facing the same issue.
Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

```
library(vegan)
library(phyloseq)
library(iCAMP)
data(GlobalPatterns)
sort(sample_sums(GlobalPatterns))
GlobalPatterns <- rarefy_even_depth(GlobalPatterns,sample.size = 50000)
count <- t(as(otu_table(GlobalPatterns), "matrix"))
count <- log1p(count)
count <- as.data.frame(decostand (count, 'hellinger'))
RCbray <- RC.pc(count, rand = 1000, weighted = TRUE)
```